# React-navigation get current navigation state in screens

Tags: javascript, react-native, react-navigation

I need to be able to get the current navigation state from my registered screen components. I expected to find a `routes` object inside the `navigation.state` object but alas its not there. I have managed to get this working by setting up my root component in the following way, however this seems convoluted and i cant help but think there must be a cleaner way to achieve this.

**App.js**

```
import React, {Component} from 'react'
import {Tabs} from './components/Routes'
import {NavigationActions} from 'react-navigation'


export default class App extends React.Component {

    state = {
        navState: null
    }

    componentDidMount(){
        const initState = Tabs.router.getStateForAction(NavigationActions.init())
        this.getState(null, initState);
    }

    getState = (prevState, newState) => {
        let activeIndex = newState.index
        let navState = newState.routes[activeIndex]
        this.setState({navState})
    }

  render() {

    return (
        <Tabs
            onNavigationStateChange={this.getState}
            screenProps={{navState: this.state.navState}}/>
    )

  }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<NavigationName
    onNavigationStateChange={(prevState, newState) => {
        this._getCurrentRouteName(newState)
    }}
/>

_getCurrentRouteName(navState) {

    if (navState.hasOwnProperty('index')) {
        this._getCurrentRouteName(navState.routes[navState.index])
    } else {
        console.log("Current Route Name:", navState.routeName)
        this.setState({navState: setCurrentRouteName(navState.routeName)})
    }
}
```

Comment: This is great, however it doesn't cover how to get the navigation state when the app initialises. Is this possible?

Comment: componentDidMount() {alert(this.props.navigation.state.key)} does it work for you?

Comment: Im not sure what you mean, i need to get my initial navigation state in my root component before any navigation actions are dispatched. This is what `const initState = Tabs.router.getStateForAction(NavigationActions.init())` is doing in my example. `onNavigationStateChange` only fires when the navigation state changes as the prop name suggests.